# rails 4 An error occurred while installing json (1.8.2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I was using the rails server this Am. Now i try to run my server on mac and I get:

```
Could not find json-1.8.2 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

So i run bundle install and I get...

```
Fetching source index from https://rubygems.org/
Using rake (10.4.2)
Using CFPropertyList (2.3.1)
Using i18n (0.7.0)

Errno::EACCES: Permission denied - /Users/danielhatcher/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/json-1.8.2/tests/test_json.rb
An error occurred while installing json (1.8.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.2'` succeeds before bundling.
```

so i try running gem install json -v '1.8.2' and get this...

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'json' (= 1.8.2) in any repository
```

any help would be greatly appreciated. I can't find anything out on the net about this.

ruby 2.0.0p247

Answer (score 0):

Are you just getting your workspace setup?

I had the same problems before when I was getting started.

I went to railsinstaller.org and development environment has been working well since then.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If I had to take a guess at this issue, I would say you opened a new shell since the `AM` and your new shell isn't configured to use the version of Ruby you installed with RVM.

I would take a look at this, https://rvm.io/rvm/basics

And basically make sure your using the version of Ruby that you installed with RVM, and that your shell is configured to use it.

And the latest version of the JSON gem appears to be `1.8.3` so you might want to try that version.  https://rubygems.org/gems/json

I hope my comments help you out.